# Voyelles orales ou nasales

Tags: phonétique, voyelles, nasalisation

La transcription de la phrase *bon anniversaire* est-elle /bɔ̃nanivɛʀsɛʀ/ ou /bɔnanivɛʀsɛʀ/ ?

La transcription de *en examen* est-elle /ɑ̃negzamɛ̃/ ou /anegzamɛ̃/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bon* suivi d'un mot commençant par une voyelle est toujours dénasalisé.

La première phrase se prononce donc /bɔnanivɛʀsɛʀ/.

La deuxième se prononce de manière régulière /ɑ̃negzamɛ̃/.

La dénasalisation est optionnelle avec d'autres mots comme par exemple *ton*:

*Ton anniversaire* se prononce indifféremment /tɔnanivɛʀsɛʀ/ ou /tɔ̃nanivɛʀsɛʀ/.