# Dénasalisation du õ

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

A l'école j'ai appris à dénasaliser la voyelle õ dans le cas de certaines liaisons comme bò-n ami, tò-n oncle, etc. Cependant, on me fait souvent la remarque en me disant que j'ai une prononciation "bizarre" pour reprendre le mot que j'entends le plus souvent. Après en avoir discuté avec un ami qui lui aussi aime la linguistique, je me suis renseigné et c'est ce qui m'a permis de mettre le mot "dénasalisation" sur ce phénomène.

> Emploi pronom. à sens passif, usuel. Perdre le caractère ou le phonème nasals. [En français] la voyelle õ se dénasalise dans quelques cas seulement : « un bò-n ami, un bò-n élève »
>
> [ Définition du CNRTL de *dénasalisation*, https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9nasalisation ]

Par ailleurs, j'ai vu un sujet [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30306/voyelles-orales-ou-nasales/30307#30307) qui évoque le phénomène brièvement. Mais mon interrogation est plus globale que ça :

- La dénasalisation est-elle acceptée dans d'autres cas qu'après "bon" comme "mon interrogation" justement ou "ton oncle" par exemple ?
- Pourquoi cette dénasalisation a-t-elle lieu et notamment pourquoi n'aurait-elle lieu en théorie que dans certains cas après "bon" ?
- A quand remonte ce phénomène dans ces cas particuliers et est-il si désuet qu'il n'y paraît ?

J'en profite pour remercier "Gaby" qui m'a transmis ce goût pour la linguistique dès mon jeune âge et qui m'a enseigné cette liaison particulière.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de raison nette et claire qui explique pourquoi ce phénomène prend place ou non.

En ce qui concerne les pratiques à suivre, il faut dire que l'on n'a jamais fait de ces questions de prononciation une matière d'enseignement dans les écoles primaires et secondaires que j'ai fréquentées ; je n'y ai personnellement jamais fais attention dans ma prononciation, et en y faisant attention je m'aperçois que je dénasalise plus ou moins « ein » dans « en plein air » mais pas « on » dans « bon ami » quand il s'agit de « ami qui est bon » alors que, au contraire, j'ai tendance à le dénasaliser lorsqu'il s'agit de « personne avec laquelle on entretient une relation à caractère sexuel ». Je ne dénasalise pas « on » dans « bon élève », « mon interrogation »,  « ton oncle »; dans « de bon augure », je tends à ne pas dénasaliser « on » mais dans « un bonhomme » je le dénasalise parfaitement, comme la prononciation standard le veut; ces façons de prononcer sont donc surtout dues à l'environnement dans lequel on se trouve lors de l'apprentissage de la langue.

Dans le département de La Manche par exemple, la dénasalisation dans le parler dialectal a atteint des mots comme « bonjour » qui peuvent se prononcer « boujour »; on trouve  dans la référence suivante, en même temps que des explications sur le phénomène de dénasalisation dans La Manche, un bref compte-rendu sur l'histoire générale de ce phénomène :
 ([ref](https://www.wikimanche.fr/D%C3%A9nasalisation)).
Tout aussi bien que l'on ne peut pas insister pour que « ton anniversaire » soit prononcé  /tɔnanivɛʀsɛʀ/ plutôt que /tɔ̃nanivɛʀsɛʀ/, on ne peut pas insister pour que la prononciation de « bon anniversaire » soit /bɔnanivɛʀsɛʀ/ plutôt que /bɔ̃nanivɛʀsɛʀ/.

Je crois que ces types particuliers de prononciation en ce qui concerne « on » doivent être tolérés, on ne peut pas reprocher à quelqu'un de différer quelque peu tant que des standards uniformes n'ont pas été établis et enracinés dans un solide système d'éducation.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ton point de vue, c'est très enrichissant :-)
A vrai dire, je ne parlais pas « d'inciter » voire « obliger » quiconque à prononcer de telle ou telle façon, c'était plus par curiosité et oui, selon l'éducation. Ta dernière phrase est excellente.